# Get json value dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
{
 "id":["123"],
 "optionid_123":"98"
}
```

I have the `id` as a variable, but from that how can I get the `optionid_*`? I tried a few things, but nothing seems to work. The `each` is inside of the appropriate function and jsonid contains the correct value. Here is my attempt at accessing the value `98` which doesn't work:

```
$.each(data.id,function(){
    var jsonid = this;
    console.log( data.optionid_+jsonid ); // doesn't work
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation):

```
console.log( data['optionid_' + jsonid] );
```

Comment: Ah ha! I tried a few bracket notations but for some reason was a little off. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop with `data.id` is not correct. That is

```
$.each(data.id, function() {..})
```

is incorrect.

For example if you `data` looks like following:

```
var data = [{
 "id":["123"],
 "optionid_123":"98"
},
{
 "id":["456"],
 "optionid_456":"99"
}];
```

Then you need to loop over `data` and get your required property.

```
$.each(data, function(index, val) {
  var jsonid = val.id[0]; // as val.id is array so you need [0] to get the value
  console.log(val['optionid_' + jsonid]); // bracket notation used
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FrnpE/2/)**